# What is the best way to conditionally display an image created via storyboard?

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout, storyboard

I'm creating a detail view screen in an app.  The content that is being shown in detail may, or may not have an image.  I am using estimated row height when displaying my cells.

The xib has the following constraints:

- Trailing Space to superview
- Leading Space to superview
- Bottom Space to superview
- Top Space to superview
- Height <= 200

This works great when I've got an image displayed, however if there is no image the cell is rendering with a height of about 40 and i'm getting a warning.

> Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously
>   suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're
>   considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height
>   instead.

What is the best way to resolve this? I really don't want to try to conditionally change the number of rows the table has based on an image attribute.

Ideally I'd like constraints that are such that use the above constraints, image displayed edge to edge, clipping is fine, with a max height of 200.  Or if there is no image the height is 0.

Code in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
 EntityContentObject *object = (EntityContentObject *)self.resultsArray[0];
 self.imageURLString = object.entityPicture;

 NSLog(@"IMAGE URL STRING: %@", self.imageURLString);

 ImageTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ideaImgCell"];

 if (!cell)
 {
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"ImageTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ideaImgCell"];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ideaImgCell"];
 }

 if([self.imageURLString isEqualToString:@""]){
     // no image to display;
 }else{
    [cell.ideaImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.imageURLString] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
 }

 NSLog(@"CELL IDEA IMAGE HEIGHT: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.ideaImage.frame));
 return cell;
```

Comment: Does the height have to be 0? A cheap shortcut would be to use 1 by setting height >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have to see this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithSelf-SizingTableViewCells.html

write these lines in your project

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       if(no image){ // put condition
          return 0; 
      }
      else{
        return 200; 
      }
    }

 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
        {
    if(no image){
     return 0; 
    }
    else{
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; 
    }

 }
```